# making random query button using $_GET

Tags: query-posts, get-posts

Im trying to make my post random when i lick on my button using $_GET but it just keeps refreshing my page instead of refreshing with the random post.

```
    <a href="<?php echo $my_query; ?>?p=random"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/shakeup.png" alt="" /></a>

<?php if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p']=='random') {?> 
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('orderby=rand'); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```

im getting this error now "Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object in"

Comment: use `query_posts();` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the direct class methods `have_posts()` or `the_post()` unless you're working with the main query. In order to modify the main query you must use `query_posts`.

If you want to create a new query object you need to call those methods from the new query object as Rarst showed in his example.

So you should be either...

- Changing the main query

  ```
  <?php query_posts('orderby=rand'); ?>

  <div id="front-video-container">

  <?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>           
  <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  ```

**NOTE:** If this query has other purposes you may need to retain existing query parameters, using an array merge or conditional `query_posts` logic.

- Or, creating a new query

  ```
  <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('orderby=rand'); ?>

  <div id="front-video-container">

  <?php if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : ?>           
  <?php while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
  ```

It's hard to say without seeing more of the code and knowing where you're placing it, i'd *assume* you will need to retain query parameters, in which case i'd suggest using the first sample and conditionalising  the `query_posts` line.. eg.

```
<?php 
if( isset( $_GET['p'] ) && 'random' == $_GET['p'] ) {
    query_posts('orderby=rand');
}
?>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are using new `WP_Query` object, but wrapper functions for main query.

Try:

```
<?php if ($my_query->have_posts()) : ?>           
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```